# Java does not release the process after writing inputstream to file

Tags: java, jersey

I am building a java RestService and try to upload an Image from the frontend and try to save it somewhere on my computer. The Problem is that I only can open the uploaded image after I closed the server. When I try to open the image while the server is still running, I just get a black image...

This is my code:

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                         String uploadedFileLocation) {

    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

That is the code where I call writeToFile()...

```
 @POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {


    String uploadedFileLocation = "c://Users/leona/Desktop/EOT/src/main/Backend_EOT/sparti-meetme-63dfc731c375/meetmeserver/src/main/webapp/" + name;

    // save it
    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    try {
        uploadedInputStream.close();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        log.debug("Input Stream konnte nicht geschlossen werden");
    }

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}
```

I really would appreciate if someone could help me with that.

Comment: In case of exceptions, your output stream won't be closed and data could be lost by the way. Also, you open the output stream twice and close it once.

Comment: Do not close the input stream. It is managed by jersey already, as closing this output stream is part of a jax-rs contract.

Comment: You can still get this problem in future  if you encounter some error while writing. Either you need to close your resources in finally block or use `try with resource` to be in safe site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're opening 2 `FileOutputStream`s but only closing one of them. here is a snippet of your code with a comment added by me, showing which line to delete:

```
try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    // delete the following line, you already opened the output stream right after the `try`.
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
```

As an aside, make sure you close the `uploadedInputStream`. It's not being closed in the code you posted. The best practice would be to close it in the same scope you create it in, which in this case would be outside of the function you posted.

### Update:

Now that we see more of the code, we see that you're being passed an `InputStream` by a framework. Let the framework handle closing it. As mentioned above, the best practice is to close streams in the scope they are created in. In this case, that would be the Jersey framework.

Comment: It's a parameter, it probably should not be closed in this method.

Comment: @sturcotte06 I mentioned that in my answer. The real problem here is that one of the `FileOutputStream`s is not being closed.

Comment: @Asaph Hey, thanks for your help! I added the code where I call writeToFile() could you pls take a look at it and tell me what I am missing?

Comment: @watchmerisxe Delete this line: `out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));`. You've opened 2 `OutputStream`s but only closed 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right way to write data to a file, from an arbitrary input stream. This ensures that the file descriptor will be flushed and closed.

```
private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation) {
    try (OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream
              (Paths.get(uploadedFileLocation), StandardOpenOption.WRITE, StandardOpenOption.CREATE)) {
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use that in android app? Because Intelij doesnt now "Files.newOutPutStream" and asked me to add an android dependency? @sturcotte06

Comment: This is java 7's nio. This is the new api for IO on java, which should be preferred to the old IO api, as it is mockable and pluggable. If it's not available on your platform, you can still use FileOutputStream's constructor to get your output stream (the rest of the code does not change).

Comment: @watchmerisxe Try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40162029/166339). It's a 1 line change and I think it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @sturcotte06 and Asaph Thank you guys! deleting the one line the opend a second outputstream solved the issue, I will post my code below for future generations. Can I upvote you guys somewhere? thanks alot!

Comment: Well you got some more issues coming if you do not ensure that the stream is closed with a try-with-resource or a try-finally statement.